# How were cattle cut out in the 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, everyday-life, agriculture, animals, labour-history

In the largest cattle raising countries - Australia and the USA, huge free ranging herds were kept. Nowadays, we use yards and crushes for husbandry activities such as drafting and calf marking  (castration, etc). Small herds can be pretty tame, but it must have been painstaking to cut calves out of a 1000 head herd with defensive mothers out in the open, keeping track of your progress and stopping them from running back in. Was this the case? Or was there a particular way? Corrals/round yards may hold the manually separated animals, but what might free grazers have done without any facilities?

Comment: I actually have some first-hand experience with this, but my grandfather used a corral to help with the separation process. I'd imagine on the free range you'd have to either find a natural barrier to help, and/or make up the difference with extra cowboys (on horseback of course). However, I don't *know* that, and now you've got me curious too, so +1 for the question.

Comment: It must have taken a lot of cowboys though. I'm thinking how a free grazer probably wasn't exceptionally rich and could manage the herd otherwise with a small number of men. And yeah, steers can be cut alright and corralled/held out, but the cow and calf instinct might have been a different problem?

Comment: Would love to hear any Oklahoman old  time wisdom you might dig up :)

Comment: Well, it might not have to be quite so "old time". It looks like a lot of the states west of here [are **still** free range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_range#Modern_times) states, and I wouldn't be shocked if many herds there were that big or larger.

Comment: Free range? Wow, that's news to me. I'll have to look into that out of interest

Comment: @Duncan  Today "Free Range" is a legal principle - it means that if your cow wanders off your property, it is still yours - and if someone runs into it with his car and kills himself, it's his own damn fault for bad driving.  Herds are still largely confined by barbed wire - but a single grazing allotment can cover many, many square miles.

Comment: This is really a silly question.  The answer is, "Pretty much like they do today."  In the American West, we still use cowboys on horseback to manage herd.  Skills like cutting and roping are not just rodeo contests but are everyday tasks.  Cutting a calf out of the herd is not easy, but it's what a cowboy does for a living.  (Or more accurately, it's how the horse earns it's oats.)

Comment: @pokep: Yes, it's mainly the horse doing the work.  (Though sometimes ATVs are used, too.)  Just moving cattle (as opposed to roping & branding them) is fairly simple: they naturally move away from your horse if you get close enough. The main difference between now and 150 years ago is that instead of driving the cattle long distances to market, or a railway, they will be gathered up and loaded on cattle trucks.  And "free range" cattle are generally grazed on public lands, with the rancher paying a fee to the BLM or Forest Service.

Comment: @jamesqf  BLM allotments and "open-range" are different concepts.  "Open-range" is simply a legal term meaning that in a specific area the burden of keeping animals off the road or off your property belongs to the owner of the road (e.g. county/states) or property, not the owner of the cattle (because fences are not perfect.)  It has nothing to do with whether a herd is, in fact, fenced in.  Also,  BLM allotments are not just rented out - they come with rules, including fence maintenance, intended to protect riparian zones, prevent overgrazing, etc... Ol'timey "open-range" doesn't much exist.

Comment: @pokep: I suppose the meaning of "open range" depends on whether you're a lawyer or not.  Hereabouts, the most common use is on the road signs you see when leaving towns, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2014-08-09_12_07_15_Open_Range_sign_along_southbound_U.S._Route_93_in_far_northern_Lincoln_County,_Nevada.JPG  And while grazing allotments may be fenced, they're areas of many square miles, rather than small pastures or feedlots, so that people still need to do the same sort of round-up.

Comment: @jamesqf  Those signs are a warning to motorists and are present regardless of whether there are fences or not.  They mean, "Drive at your own risk!".  And on our ranch we didn't call moving the cattle from allotment to allotment a "round-up" - that's way overblown.  Here's the upshot - on our ranch (1000-head cow-calf operation in the High Desert of Eastern Oregon, with 6000 private acres and about 50 sq miles in allotments), it was "open-range", but our cowboys spent far more time repairing fences than moving cattle.

Comment: @pokep: You miss my point.  Those signs are what "open range" means to people who aren't lawyers (or getting grazing from BLM/USFS): that there are cattle roaming around out there, and that there are no fences to keep them off the roads.  Which is true of all the public land grazing I've seen (northern Nevada/northeastern California, mostly): the fences are there to separate grazing areas (and occasionally block off riparian areas &c), not to separate cattle from roads.  The fence lines typically go straight across the roads, with cattle guards.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_grid

Comment: @jamesqf  But you miss my point, which is that the land you describe is not at all what most people think of when they hear the words "open range".  There are no "round-ups" - moving a herd from allotment to allotment takes one or two cowboys a couple hours.  In fact, our cowboys spent far more time fixing fences than they ever spent moving cattle.  (Fun fact: in many ranches, the fences are the most valuable type of capital stock - worth more than the barns, corrals, or machinery.)

Comment: @pokep: Certainly there are round-ups.  Perhaps not where you are, but I see them every fall, and have a couple of friends who help out as extra riders on them.  The grazing lands are not always, or even often, contiguous with the ranches.  They are often in the higher elevations, where winter snow is likely to be a good bit deeper than a cow.  The cattle are moved there in the spring, left basically alone until fall, then moved back.

Comment: We do the same thing in Oregon - our ranch also had winter and summer allotments, not contiguous - but calling it a "round-up" makes it sound like its a helluva lot more than it is. Moving cattle is a routine operation on any ranch, and your "round-up" is just a day when you move them farther. I don't care for the romanticization of ranching - today, most of America sees ranchers through the lens of the Bundy family, as people alienated from conventional society. In truth a ranch is just a grass-to-meat factory, and most ranchers spend more time on the computer than in the saddle.

Comment: They actually use helicopters and drones now on the King and Kennedy ranches.  Of course that is in addition to the usual cowboys on horses.  This is an interesting video of it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8trsv1BtbCY

Answer (score 4):

### Then and now, the trained cattle dog.

Most of the large herds running in Australia were not as free as the question implies. Large [cattle stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_station) and runs in Australia did have conveniently located infrastructure like yards, paddocks, and dams for concentrating and holding animals for processing. Herds would be moved over long distances and divided as desired into manageable batches with skilled horsemen and [highly trained cattle dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Cattle_Dog). A genuinely rootless [drover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drover_(Australian)), to the extent such actually existed, would simply have to be very good at improvising or borrowing facilities along their way as needed. A trail-blazer would build with an eye to future requirements, a free-loader would borrow or make temporary improvizations. With good dogs and skilled riders, isolating and controlling the animals would be the least of their problems.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why the down-vote. The Australian cattle dog was bred especially and precisely to deal with the exact situation described by the questioner - the need to divide and control large herds of wild untamed cattle.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen here in UK demonstrations by U.S. cowboys of cutting into a herd with a larriot, and very effective it is. So many of the cowboy films show herds being driven at speed for miles, which is far from the truth. WE presumably are talking about domestic breeds rather than buffalo, even if they are roaming in a wild context. The stock would never get any flesh on them if they were constantly being run all the way to the rail-head. So, cattle being quite curious, will not charge away unless the stockman charges at them, and I daresay for branding and castration it would not be too difficult to take out stirks from quite a large free-ranging herd.

Answer (score 1):

The process of collecting and separating free-range cattle in early California was the *rodeo* (which later gave its name to a sporting event). These were held at specifically suited locations; place names in both Northern and Southern California refer to the practice.

Several Indian cowboys on horseback (often they were the only Indians locally allowed to ride horses), moving faster than the cattle, could force these into a dense, round whorl with the wranglers at the perimeter. They would then extract individual cattle from the rodeo, for branding or slaughter, by lassooing them with a horsehair [lariat (*reata*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso).

There are a few details in Burcham's "Cattle and range forage in California: 1770-1880". Also see Cleland's "The Cattle on a Thousand Hills".

Answer (score -1):

Australian cattle industry was part of the frontier wars and settler process.  It was a capital intensive form of guerilla and economic warfare, and was backed by massive state-capital apparatuses in capital cities.

Cattle runs were sold or leased in head to extremely rich well connected families of old British capital, or extremely successful second generation Australian capital.  The Downers of the 19th century in South Australia are an example of this kind of group.

Leasees in chief or owners would sublet on the basis of a certain body of cattle having to be on the run by a certain time.  These anticipated growth requirements involved the destruction of aboriginal nations' economies and domestic economies, and this usually involved informal warfare.  Sub-lettors would hire station managers as employees with profit sharing arrangments to actually live remotely.  These station owners would recruit men, including out of country aboriginal men, to actually conduct the day to day business and warfare.

This was capital intensive industry requiring complex difficult to maintain beasts, moveable tools (rifles etc.), fixed capital infrastructure, and skilled and semi-skilled labour.

The concentrations of water, and the presence of capital goods allowing for coralling at watering points, or stock movement points, allowed for concentrated separation, including capitalisation through fixed plant and equipment.

Transport, being via fixed allowance driving routes also allowed for concentration.

Finally the chief gambit for agricultural companies was capital seizure not rent.  The sub-tenant would fail stocking requirements and their stock and improvement seized via bankruptcy.  The successful station manager would finally buy his lease from the company, instead of being an employee on profit sharing.  And drought would wipe them out and the tenant in chief would bankrupt them and resume their ownership with all the improvements made.  At the heart of this strategy is *capitalisation*, not a romantic wilderness, but pounds and shillings of wire and wood.

Noel Butlin is the seminal economic historian of the industry for the 19th century, though more recent works have developed the role of cattle capital in massacre and economic warfare.